# Python cannot find newly installed module

Tags: python, pip, python-module

I've created a module using the following setup.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Learn more: https://github.com/kennethreitz/setup.py

from setuptools import setup, find_packages


with open('README.md') as f:
    readme = f.read()

with open('LICENSE') as f:
    license = f.read()

setup(
    name='mymod',
    version='1.0a1',
    description='test',
    long_description=readme,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    author='Ray Salemi',
    author_email='ray@raysalemi.com',
    url='https://rayboston@bitbucket.org/rayboston/mymod',
    license=license,
    packages=find_packages(exclude=('tests', 'docs', 'examples'))
)
```

But when I try to install it using

```sh
% python setup.py install
```

I see that it gets installed in my site packages:

```
Processing mymod-1.0a1-py3.8.egg
Copying mymod-1.0a1-py3.8.egg to /Users/raysalemi/PycharmProjects/testenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Adding mymod 1.0a1 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /Users/raysalemi/PycharmProjects/testenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mymod-1.0a1-py3.8.egg
Processing dependencies for mymod==1.0a1
Finished processing dependencies for mymod==1.0a1
(testenv) (base) raysalemi@WriteNow mymod % cd ../testenv
(testenv) (base) raysalemi@WriteNow testenv % python
Python 3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 11:26:31)
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mymod
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mymod'
```

How do I debug this?  I can't see an error.

I'm running Big Sur 11.0.1 and
Python 3.8.3 from Anaconda

Pip shows the module is there

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        20.3.1
mymod      1.0a1
setuptools 41.2.0
```

The problem is that the package is being misnamed:

```
(testenv) (base) raysalemi@WriteNow site-packages % ls
__pycache__         mymod-1.0a0-py3.8.egg
easy-install.pth        mymod-1.0a0.dist-info
easy_install.py         setuptools
pip             setuptools-41.2.0.dist-info
pip-20.3.1.dist-info        src
pkg_resources
```

It is `mymod-1.0a0-py3.8.egg` instead of `mymod`

Comment: Wait, in `setup.py` your module is called `mymod`, in your code you import `memos`, and the error message is about a module called `memo`? Looks like autocorrect has been messing with the module's name

Comment: That was an autocorrect mistake. I had to rename the actual module name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug you can run the setup:

```bash
python setup.py sdist --formats=gztar
```

and unzip the resulting `.tar.gz` file and check if all your source code files are in it.
(or use `--formats=zip` instead of `gztar` to get a simpler file to extract)

The resulting package is always of the form `package_name-package_version`, so the name you received is **not** incorrect. (In case you are wondering, you can find the valid package_version formatting rules [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#public-version-identifiers).)

You can later use this package by adding it to the `requirements.txt` file of the project you want to be dependent on it. E.g.

```python
my-package>=1.2.0,<2.0.0
```

In your case, since the version is a pre-release (`mymod-1.0a0-py3.8.egg` ==> version is `1.0a0-py3.8.egg` which means version `1.0` pre-relase version `alpha0-py3.8`).

The version `1.0a0-py3.8.egg` < than version `1.0` (pre-release always < release with same number), so you will need something like `>0,<2.0`.

Personally, I put the source code in the repo under `src/` and then select these files in setup.py using:

```python
packages=find_namespace_packages(where="src")
```

There are other parameters I recommend using e.g. make sure environment has a new enough `setuptools` to recognize `find_namespace_packages`, take list of dependencies from `requirements.txt` files etc.:

```python
from setuptools import setup, find_namespace_packages


with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    required = f.read().splitlines()

setup(
    name='your_project_name',
    version='1.0.0',
    description='your project description',
    url='your repo url',
    author='your username',
    author_email='your email',
    license='your license type',
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    setup_requires='setuptools>=45.2.0',
    packages=find_namespace_packages(where="src"),
    install_requires=required,
    data_files=['requirements.txt'],
    include_package_data=True
)
```

See the full list of options and what they are for in the [documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/keywords.html).

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.

My source directory was named `src` not `mymod`.  So there was a `src` directory in `site-packages` instead of a `mymod` directory.  This is a surprise since the package is named in `setup.py`.